# Ubuntu 18.04 - How to change an application icon

Tags: 18.04, icons

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but the answers did not work for me.

In my C programming directory, I have a number of compiled applications, all of which run fine.  In the properties panel of each it shows that they are executable and are using the 'Run Software' as the default program.  However, some have an icon which makes them look like a text file, whereas others have the more usual grey 'Run' icon.  I want to change the icons of those which look like a text file into the more normal grey 'Run' icon.  I have not yet found a way which works.  Any ideas?